# sql server how to add a column to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

A view is created use the following sql:

```
create view [dbo].[tblDimSession] AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(CDH_DEV_BJ_LS, 'select * from Session')
```

This view is created by accessing data with Hive.

I want to add a new column named `sessionID`, `int` type, must be an auto-increased column.

How to alter the view, or could the column be added when creating the view?

Thank you.

Comment: You should read up on "ALTER" table/view for your database. Unrelated: It is not good practice to select star (*) from a table/view. This hampers the optimizer and in the case of SQL Server new columns in the source will not show up despite the star unless you explicitly recompile the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want additional column to the view, it can be done during `CREATE VIEW` or `ALTER VIEW` in your case of adding auto-increment column it should be done on the table and than just added to view. But if you must add it to the view you can do it the following way.

`CREATE VIEW MyView as Select *, MyExtraColumn From MyTable` unlike `ALTER TABLE` you do not need to specify `ADD` or `DROP` statement, modifying view can be compared more to altering SP or table function. To add column that auto-increments you can do this

`ALTER VIEW MyView as SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyUniqueColumn) AS sessionID FROM MyTable`

Note if you doing `ORDER BY` a column that is not unique your number could change every time you execute it.